# Dull colors in Adobe Illustrator CS6 with RGB mode

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS6. I have a document in RGB mode, with Web preset. My color settings are:

> [Working Spaces]
>
> RGB: sRGB IEC61966-2.1 CMYK: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
>
> [Color Management Policies]
>
> RGB: Preserve Embedded Profiles CMYK: Preserve Numbers (Ignore Linked
>   Profiles)
>
> [Conversion Options]
>
> Engine: Adobe (ACE) Intent: Relative Colorimetric

And my colors are duller than normally. If I open my document **in another computer**, I can see the **correct colors**.

Just look at my color picker:

[image: http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/641/colorpickerwrong.jpg]

And as it should look like:

[image: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/8996/colorpickerok.jpg]

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Calibrated your monitor recently? Simply looks like a possibly corrupt profile. Recalibrating the monitor should help.

Comment: You're a genius! I "installed" a .icc file and nothing happened... I have removed it and my colors are correct now. I can't figure out why it only affected to Illustrator and not to Photoshop.

I can't mark your comment as correct answer since it's not actually an answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Made it an answer :) Photoshop color manages the picker... Illustrator allows the OS to manage the picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recalibrate your monitor.

You probably have a corrupt color profile which is causing the issue. Recalibrating will overwrite a corrupt profile.